# Can't download Excel Files from website ASP NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm hosting an ASP.NET Core MVC website that serves as an intranet that allows users to upload documents and attach files to them. I'm currently uploading the files by converting them into a `Byte` `Array` and storing the files in a database table.

Currently every file type (eg: `.docx`,`.pdf`,`.jpg`) can be uploaded and downloaded completely fine into the correct formats, EXCEPT `.xlsx` and `.xlsm` files - they can be uploaded but whenever I try to download either file I get an error:

> An error occurred while processing your request.
> Request ID: XX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX-XX
>
> Development Mode
> Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.
>
> The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications.
> It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users.
> For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app.

Normally this wouldn't be a problem, I'd just go back into the code and debug through it, but when I do that I get no error and the files download fine, any ideas at all would be helpful because I don't even know where to start trying to fix this at the moment

Comment: Did you set the environment variable to IIS or update your web.config file? ASP.NET Core configures app behavior based on the runtime environment using an environment variable.To determine the runtime environment, ASP.NET Core reads from the following environment variables:

1.`DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT`  
2.`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` when ConfigureWebHostDefaults is called. The default ASP.NET Core web app templates call ConfigureWebHostDefaults. The ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value overrides DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT.

Please follow the steps in this doc to set the environment variable.